# How would I filtering documents with a certain order query in Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, nosql

#### Background

I am trying to implement a blocking feature on my social media application. Currently, one of the feed queries sorts/ orders documents by their created timestamp in chronological order.

#### Proposed Solution

In order to be published on the apple app store we need to implement a blocking feature. I thought easy, create a field within the user document that has a string array of "blockedUsers." Now when you query for the field, use the `not in` operator that Firestore supports and boom you can have a list of documents that are:

- `not in` the blockedUsers array
- ordered `by` completedTimestamp
- `limit` to x for pagination reasons

#### Issue

However, after reading the documentation for `in` and `not in` operators, you cannot order documents by a different field than the comparison field you are filtering. In this case `not in`.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

#### Question

I am somewhat at a loss on how to structurally implement a blocked feature that will filter documents in our GlobalPosts collection excluding blocked users, ordered chronologically, with pagination.

I would love to hear any proposed solutions, dont worry if it breaks our current schema it may foster some other ideas, however keeping our current schema is preferable.

Comment: What you're trying to do is not possible with a single Firestore query, no matter how you structure the data.  At the very least, you will need a combination of multiple queries and some client side sorting or filtering.  It will likely be more expensive than you'd like.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for the advice, a simple client-side filter was able to handle our feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as a Community Wiki since it's based on Doug Stevenson's comment to the question:

What you're trying to do is not possible with a single Firestore query, no matter how you structure your data, due to the limitations that you shared from the documentation.

So you would need a combination of multiple queries and some client side sorting or filtering and this will likely be more expensive than you'd like.